# Authentication in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Which authentication sql server is more secure windows or sqlserver authentication? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out articles on this subject

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/authentication.htm

http://www.geekpedia.com/KB101_What-is-the-difference-between-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Authentication.html

http://database.ittoolbox.com/documents/windows-authentication-vs-sql-server-authentication-18609

Ask if you need additional help.